# jQuery not at all working?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to learn jQuery and I don't understand why it doesn't at all work. My index.html is simple, as you can see below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQuery Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
    $(function() { alert("Hello world!"); });

    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am hosting the website with XAMPP in my local machine, and the file structure is this, under htdocs:

```
XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs
...
jquerytuts2/
  index.html
  /js
    jquery-1.8.0.js
    jquery-1.8.0.min.js
```

The jQuery just displays as it is in the browser, plain text. I've seen this on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and I am using a 2012 MacBook Pro running OSX 10.8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQuery Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() { alert("Hello world!"); });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Explanation: Because the document usually gets executed from top to bottom, you execute jQuery code before jQuery itself is loaded, causing the site to blow up. Oh yeah, and you forgot to wrap a `<script>` tag around your JavaScript code.

Edit: And some further advice: Unless you have a reason not to do so, place your javascript below anything else in the site. That causes the site to load faster. There are HTML5 attributes for script tags that make this unneccessary (in theory).

Comment: What an awfully easy mistake that was. Banging my head on a wall now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use jQuery DOM ready method (`$(function() { ... })`) before you include the library in the document. And yes, don't forget to use `<script></script>` tags for your JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQuery Tutorial</title>

    <!-- place your code here: -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- and don't forget the tags: -->
    <script>
        $(function() { alert("Hello world!"); });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uh, it was not my intention to "steal" your answer.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer It's OK. I don't really care about these minor things. And obviously you need reputation more than me :)

Answer (score 0):

hey there is problem in your code..
you need to put your jquery code in script tag

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>JQuery Tutorial</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() { alert("Hello world!"); });
</script>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**NOTE**

There is no need to put your jquery file at top and then call the ready function. How Browser renders DOM is it downloads all the external files css,js etc.. and then it goes for inline tags. here since it is on ready it will not effect wherever you put your code in page. But if you wrote the same thing in external js file and then you included it before jquery file it would certainly give you a error..